# Making sense of: "there is an uncountable set" is a logical consequence of $\mathrm{ZFC}$, yet $\mathrm{ZFC}$ is satisfiable in a countable domain.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

As I learn the Compactness and Löwenheim-Skolem theorems of first-order logic and I begin to have a better understanding of what they really mean, something has me baffled.

As I have learned it, the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem says that if a set $S$ of $L$-sentences of a first-order language $L$ is satisfiable at all, then $S$ is satisfiable in a countable structure.

Now, mathematics proves the existence of uncountable sets. To be more specific, take the language $L$ of set theory, and let $\mathrm{ZFC}$ denote the set of axioms of set theory with the axiom of choice. Then, $\mathrm{ZFC}$ is a set of $L$-sentences and (if consistent) by the Löwenheim-Skolem it must be satisfiable in an $L$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ having a countable domain. On the other hand, the statement *there is an uncountable set* can be expressed as an $L$-sentence $\sigma$, and $S\vDash\sigma$, i.e. the existence of an uncountable set is a logical conclusion $\mathrm{ZFC}$.

Hence, the axioms which allow us to conclude that an uncountable set exists are themselves satisfied by a countable set. I am a novice, and my question is: Is there a particular meaning that professional logicians are giving to this situation? Am I suppose to interpret it in a particular way? It is quite remarkable!

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3989368/keeping-track-of-proper-classes-vs-sets-when-showing-zfc-has-a-countable-model) MSE question is related.

Comment: The fact that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves "There is an uncountable set" means that any model $\mathcal{M}$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ has something(s) it thinks is uncountable. However, $\mathcal{M}$'s notion of uncountability may not be correct: something $\mathcal{M}$ thinks is uncountable might actually be countable! This is guaranteed to happen, for example, if $\mathcal{M}$ itself is countable. (Technically the opposite is also true, but this can only occur in "non-$\omega$-models" - since these are a bit more mysterious, this is usually put off until later.)

Comment: It may de-mystify things to note that **every** model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is wrong about "proper-class-hood:" if $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then $\mathcal{M}$ thinks $\mathcal{M}$ is a proper class but $\mathcal{M}$ is in fact a set. (There's less here than meets the eye: remember, models *are required to be sets.*) Skolem's paradox is not really any different.

Comment: @NoahSchweber You know what? That notion of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ thinks... is precisely what I had in mind. But not in any concrete sense, mathematically speaking. Skolem's paradox? I see, I will look it up.

Comment: "That notion of ZFC thinks..." Careful! It's important to distinguish between what $\mathsf{ZFC}$ thinks (= stuff provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$) and what some particular model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ thinks (of course "$\mathsf{ZFC}$ thinks X" is equivalent to "every model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ thinks X," but individual models can - and have to - deviate from $\mathsf{ZFC}$'s limited confidences). And then, of course, there's the third notion of "actually true" (= "true in $V$") - if we take a Platonist stance, anyways ...

Comment: Good point, I interpreted $\mathrm{ZFC}$ thinks semantically, as "it's logical conclusions". Besides Tableaux I have not learned other syntactic proof systems.